# Classic ASP dropdown menus, hold values

Tags: asp-classic

i'm working on something. So, i go to my Database and I want to ask what type of machine they want (base on the existings at the DB)
Then, i will check the model, depending on the type.
Last, The number of palets

exampe: 
machine 1 has model 2, 3 and 4
machine 2 has model 1, 2 and 3
machine 1, model 2 has 13 palets, machine 2 model 2 has 15 palets

my code:
**main.asp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="javascript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
<!--Inicialization, ...-->
        <%
            dim model, typee, palete
            typee=""
            model=""
            palete=""
            dim perguntas(20)

            Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            Set conn2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            conn_string = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=INF0148\SQLEXPRESS;Database=#####;Uid=####;Pwd=###########"
            conn.commandTimeout = 60
            conn.Open conn_string 
            Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            Set rs2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            function options(value, data, select_id) 
                Response.Write ("<option value=""" & value & """")
                if request.form(select_id) = value then 
                    Response.Write ("selected")
                end if
                Response.Write(">" & data & "</option>")
            end function

        %>

        <div id="main">
<!--choose type of machine-->               
            <form method="post">
                <select name="maq" id="maq" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="">Type of Machine:</option>
                    <%
                        conn.close
                        conn.Open conn_string
                        rs.Open "SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM models", conn
                        do until rs.EOF
                            for each x in rs.Fields
                                options x.value, x.value, "maq"
                            next
                            rs.MoveNext
                        loop        
                    %>
                </select>
            </form>

            <%typee=Request.Form("maq")%>


<!--Choose model-->             
            <form method="form">
                <select name="model" id="model" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="">Model:</option>
                    <%  
                        conn.close
                        conn.Open conn_string
                        rs.Open  "SELECT DISTINCT Model FROM models WHERE Type='"&typee&"'", conn
                        do until rs.EOF
                            for each x in rs.Fields
                                options x.value, x.value, "model"
                            next
                            rs.MoveNext
                        loop        
                        model=Request.Form("model")
                    %>
                </select>
            </form>

<!--Number of Palets-->             
            <form method="post">
                <%
                    conn.close
                    conn.Open conn_string                   
                    rs.Open "SELECT N_Palets FROM Models WHERE Type='"&typee&"' AND Model='"&model&"'", conn
                    dim temp
                    temp=0
                    do until rs.EOF
                        for each x in rs.Fields
                            if not IsNull(x.value) then
                                if temp=0 then
                                    response.write("<select name=palets id=palets onchange=""this.form.submit()"";>")
                                    response.write("<option value="">Number of Palets:</option>")  
                                    temp=1
                                end if
                                options x.value, x.value, "palets"
                            end if
                        next
                        rs.MoveNext
                    loop        
                    paletes=Request.Form("palets")                  
                %>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

so, when i choose the type... it's ok, the page displays the right models... when i choose the model, page reload and i loose everything.

Can you help me?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection for one thing - but also I suggest moving your business logic (database code, etc) out from your HTML and doing as much processing as possible at the very top of the file before you've sent anything to the client, as that will make everything easier to follow.

Comment: i didn't understand, easier to follow? and, how can i put less in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting a form only submits the fields that are on that form, not any of the other fields on other forms. That's why submitting one of your child forms loses everything. To fix it, add hidden fields with the necessary parent data.

```
<!--Choose model-->             
   <form method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="maq" value="<%=Request.Form("maq")%>">
       <select name="model" id="model" onchange="this.form.submit()">
       [...]
       </select>
   </form>
```

For the palets form, add both the machine & model as hidden fields.

Comment: A few observations in addition to Martha's answer... 1) do not close your connection after each use of recordset, 2) remove the reference to conn2... you can use an open connection as many times as you like, and 3) close your recordsets after use. Hope this helps.

Comment: and how can i put this to work with the 3rd dropdown?

Comment: @LuísMelo: like I said, for the third form, you'll need hidden fields for both the machine & the model.